# data.table J argument: function with 2 arguments by two groups with one fixed subset

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using the `J` argument of data.table to get the confidence interval of my variable, like so:

```
mt=data.table(mtcars)
mt_m=mt[,.(qsec=mean(qsec),CI1=t.test(qsec)$conf.int[1],CI2=t.test(qsec)$conf.int[2]),.(cyl)]
mt_m
   cyl     qsec      CI1      CI2
1:   6 17.97714 16.39856 19.55573
2:   4 19.13727 18.00699 20.26755
3:   8 16.77214 16.08159 17.46270
```

Very useful to plot mean and errorbars. But now I would like to test each condition against my control and get the p-value, something like `mt[,.(p=t.test(qsec,qsec[cyl%in%4])$p.value),.(cyl)]` (which obviously doesn't work).

> Error in t.test.default(qsec, qsec[cyl %in% 4]) : 
>     not enough 'y' observations
>
> Error in complete.cases(x, y) :
>     not all arguments have the same length `(paired test)`

Is there a way to achieve this using data.table?

**EDIT**

Mike's answer works in the case of this first MWE, with only one group. However, my data table has two:

```
dt=data.table(var1=c(rep(1,18),rep(2,18),rep(3,18)),
              var2=rep(c("A","B","C"),54),score=runif(162))
dt_m=dt[,list(score=mean(score),CI1=TCI1(score),CI2=TCI2(score),
              p=t.test(score,dt[var2%in%"A",score])$p.value),
        .(var1,var2)]
dt_m
   var1 var2     score       CI1       CI2         p
1:    1    A 0.5291396 0.3737159 0.6845634 0.6062132
2:    1    B 0.4784482 0.3426129 0.6142835 0.9326820
3:    1    C 0.5445497 0.4079861 0.6811133 0.4452131
4:    2    A 0.5047712 0.3519982 0.6575442 0.8146140
5:    2    B 0.4717234 0.3406157 0.6028311 0.8605529
6:    2    C 0.4670736 0.3273769 0.6067704 0.8205882
7:    3    A 0.4210423 0.2671292 0.5749555 0.4531821
8:    3    B 0.4392489 0.2828231 0.5956746 0.5952569
9:    3    C 0.4308970 0.3267391 0.5350549 0.4078637
```

The t test isn't computed by `var2` & `var1`, otherwise `p` would be 1 when `var2` is `A`, resulting in the same error when using a paired test.

**How to achieve this with two groups?**

Comment: The error is in the way you try to do your `t.test` not in your `data.table` code

Comment: The point is to apply my t test by `cyl` value, if I detail the arguments of `t.test` then I have to set a fixed `cyl`. I know that `data.table` handles such syntax, with `diff:=qsec-qsec[cyl%in%4]` for example. That's what I'm trying to reproduce.

Comment: Sorry! I had misread the question initially...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
mt[,.(p=t.test(qsec,mt[cyl%in%4, qsec])$p.value),.(cyl)]

#   cyl           p
#1:   6 0.181367998
#2:   4 1.000000000
#3:   8 0.001004706
```

Since you want to do the tests by `cyl` to access the reference vector (where cyl == 4) you need to a call to `mt`.

**EDIT:**
For the edited data, is this what you want?

```
dt_m=dt[,list(score = mean(score),
              p     = t.test( score, dt[ var2 %in% "A" & var1 == .SD[,var1], score], paired = T)$p.value),
        .(var1,var2), .SDcols = c("var1","score")]
dt_m

#   var1 var2     score          p
#1:    1    A 0.5315900        NaN
#2:    1    B 0.4632127 0.43045276
#3:    1    C 0.5630583 0.77617068
#4:    2    A 0.4084932        NaN
#5:    2    B 0.4977118 0.34873263
#6:    2    C 0.5238550 0.29289210
#7:    3    A 0.3653734        NaN
#8:    3    B 0.6186752 0.03029701
#9:    3    C 0.4629279 0.23013739
```

In the future, it would be helpful for you to post the actual use case from the start, that makes it much easier to come up with the solution that works instead of having to continue to go back and forth.

Comment: That's nice, it seems to work with one `by` level, but not with two unfortunately...

Comment: If you have two by levels, just put in the extra reference group after the `cyl %in% 4`. If you post a reproducible example, we can help you better

Comment: E.g.: `mt[,.(p=t.test(qsec,mt[cyl%in%4 & am == 1, qsec])$p.value),.(cyl, am)]
`

Comment: Sorry, I must have messed with my data because it worked when I ran my script again! Thank you very much

Comment: Hum, however I still get the error about length with a paired test... any idea why ?

Comment: Could it be that one of your groups has very few observations?

Comment: See my edit, every group has 18 observations. My guess is that the test takes all of the `var1` options as a second argument instead of doing first `1`, then `2`, then `3`, resulting in unequal lengths.
EDIT: this is probably the case since the p-value should be 1 or NA when `var2=="A"`.

Comment: The p-value shouldnt necessarily be 1 when var2 = A. This is b/c you are grouping by two variables. So when you use var2 = A as a comparator you are getting ALL the var2 (including var1 = 1 and var1 = 2, etc.).

Comment: The issue is that if you do a paired test, you need the data to be the same length. You comparator is ALL var2 = A while your individual groups are grouped by var2 & var1. This causes differences in the lengths. If you want it to be the same length, I suggest using var2 = A and a specific value of Var1 as a comparator

Comment: Try, `dt_m=dt[,list(score=mean(score),CI1=TCI1(score),CI2=TCI2(sco‌​re), p=t.test(score,dt[var2%in%"A" & var1==1,score], paired = T)$p.value), .(var1,var2)]`

Comment: Yeah, but in this case var1 is fixed as well, right? On the contrary, I want it to be the same between the two elements of my t test, but variable - ie, 1 then 2 then 3.

Comment: I need the test to be computed such as `for(v1 in var1){for(v2 in var2){t.test(dt[var1%in%v1&var2%in%v2]$score,dt[var1%in%v1&var2%in%"A"]$score,paired=T)}}`

Comment: Sorry for the bad MWE, I figured that using a base dataset would be easier and I thought the answer would be verstaile enough to work in any case. Thanks a lot for your time.
About your answer, what if `var1` is not a number? If you replace `1 2 3` by `"X" "Y" "Z"` it returns `Error : object 'score' not found`